# Passing parameter string UPTO jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for how to pass a string into jenkins so I can use it when sending mail.

So let say I have a file with a string inside and I want to read that file and use it inside jenkins when I send an email after finished succesfully - is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If looking for a simple string to pass, like a one-liner, 
the easiest way is probably to use **Inject parameters Plugin** -
it accepts files in INI-file format, so you could write something like this:

```
MY_PARAM1=My Line to Show in the Email
```

Then you can use ${MY_PARAM1} in your mail-template.